# Android - Webview background request

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Shortly, I have a `website loaded in webview`. Is there any way to make some kind of **background request** in the same webview so I don't loose loaded website from first load request?

Comment: Purpose of background request?

Comment: And what kind of request? Rest request to the api or some js code to be invoked?

Comment: It's a call to the backend using url that returns a JSON file